# Account kit crashes in splitscreen mode

Tags: android, facebook, account-kit

I have trouble with account kit, it crashes on entering phone number screen in split screen mode.

Im using next dependencies with last versions.

*implementation     'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.34.0'*

Here is stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.appname.dev, PID: 25576
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appname.dev/com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class TextView
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2906)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4778)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1611)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class TextView
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class TextView
               Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 37 to dimension: type=0x1
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:730)
                  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4998)
                  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:824)
                  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:818)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ab.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:76)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ab.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:72)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.a(AppCompatViewInflater.java:176)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.a(AppCompatViewInflater.java:101)
                  at android.support.v7.app.j.b(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
                  at android.support.v7.app.j.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                  at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.be$a.a(TitleFragmentFactory.java:87)
                  at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.ai.onCreateView(LoginFragment.java:43)
                  at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.be$a.onCreateView(TitleFragmentFactory.java:50)
                  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2611)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1276)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1549)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1611)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMoveToState(FragmentManager.java:3039)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2991)
                  at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:178)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreateCommon(Activity.java:6969)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6977)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2906)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4778)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1611)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Android 8.0
Xiaomi Mi A1

Comment: Post your stacktrace. It's impossible for us to guess what your issue is.

Comment: If I was your place ask this questions in [XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com) center that made just for android developers.

Comment: added stack. 
Should I add video for example?